# sync 2 files on linux

Tags: linux, rsync

I have 2 sets of files on 2 linux servers and I want to keep them in sync.  is rsync the best tool for this?  if 2 files have the same name, I will want to sync to the file with the latest modified time. is this possible?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `rsync` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command should sync both files to the latest version:

```
rsync -u file1 file2; rsync -u file2 file1
```

It is always better to test it on some temporary files before trying commands on important files, or make a backup.